# Mount error(6) when trying to mount a network path on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-2, mount, ubuntu

I am trying to mount a folder from one Raspberry Pi to another one.

The Raspberry Pi I am trying to mount is running Ubuntu Mate and I have shared the folder and gave it guest access and write access.

The Pi which I am trying to add the mount to is running Raspbian.

So far I have tried to mount the drive by using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.177.43.200/home/administrator/Test /media/NetworkDrive -o username=user,password=pass
```

and by editing the `fstab` and adding:

```
//10.177.43.200/home/administrator/Test /media/NetworkDrive cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

but both results give me the same error:

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks everyone!

Comment: Also for those wondering I can successfully ping the host server and all the user names and passwords match the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that after working all day on this I have finally figured it out.

On my Raspberry Pi that i was using as the server (the one running Ubuntu Mate) I told it which folder I wanted to share.

In my edits to the fstab I had the server location as `//10.177.43.200/home/administrator/Test`, however since i already declared which folder i wanted to share all I had to do was point to the shared folder which was previously declared.

So the corrected fstab should be as follows:

```
//10.177.43.200/Test /media/NetworkDrive cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Also this was just to test if i could mount my drive successfully so if you are to use this in a real application I highly recommend you use a credentials file